# Why is part of my dataset colored by spyder, and part is not?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, types, spyder

I have data set, and there is something wrong with it fundamentally and I don't understand what.

Till I get to index 4807 everything is ok, and afterwards isn't. All datatypes are float64.

[image]

Image on the left is good data, and you can see that Spyder adds colors to it, while on right it doesn't.

Comment: Background color and column min max aren't chosen in the right-hand window.

Comment: You can't select it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two different dataframes and I suspect that the one on the right, i.e. train-bad is very large. If so, you need to know that the coloring is not available if the contents of your Dataframe are too large. This is to avaoid lags when browsing.